# If $x^2 + ax - b$ is a factor of $x^3 - 2bx^2 + ax -6$, show that $a = -2b -6/b$.

Tags: quadratics

> If $x^2 + ax - b$ is a factor of $x^3 - 2bx^2 + ax -6$, show that $a = -2b -6/b$.

Comment: Try using polynomial long division.

Comment: I did and I get a = -2b but but can't seem to get the -6/b

Comment: Can you show us what you did? You might have forgotten to carry the $-6$ term.

Comment: Through long division I get -2bx^2 - ax^2 + ax + bx - 6 = 0

Comment: I also tried to let the other factor equal (x - q)

Comment: We know that $q(x^2+ax-b) = (-2b-a)x^2 + (a+b)x - 6$. Now we can compare coefficients. Also we do not have the $=0$ since this is not an equation.

Comment: this seems  just  the first step of dividing!  you have to continue.

Comment: Not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^3-2bx^2+ax-6$ has the factor $x^2+ax-b$. Suppose the other factor is $x-q$. Then:

$$(x-q)(x^2+ax+b)=x^3-2bx^2+ax-6$$

But by expanding:

$$(x-q)(x^2+ax+b)=x^3-qx^2+ax^2-qax+bx-qb=x^3+(a-q)x^2+(b-aq)x-bq$$

By comparing coefficients we have the equations:

$$a-q=-2b, \quad b-aq = a, \quad -bq=6$$

Hence $q=a+2b$ and $6 = -b(a+2b)$. This will reduce to $a = -2b-6/b$.

Comment: Thank You buddy!